# RequireJS, Angular, Sharing factory between modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

We are using requirejs and angular. Right now we try to share a factory between different modules and can't get things working.

How is it possible to access http services in a controller/our app?

We include our Service file the requirejs way (small extract):

```
requirejs.config( {
    paths: {
        httpServices: 'apps/services/Http'
    }
} );
```

In addition to that we have our app javascript file where we inject our dependencies (the httpService):

```
define( ['angularAMD', "httpServices", 'ngRoute', 'underscore'], function (angularAMD, httpServices) {
var app = angular.module( "clientapp", ['ngRoute'] );

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( "script" );
var myScript = _.find( scripts, function (s) {
    return s.src.substr( s.src.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1, s.src.length ) === 'index.js';
} );
var url = myScript.src.replace( "index.js", "" ) + "partials/";

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when( '/', {
                templateUrl: url + "dashboard.html"
            } )
            .when( '/basicdata/index/', {
                templateUrl: url + "basicdata/index.html"
            } )
    } );

return angularAMD.bootstrap( app );
} );
```

Finally the service itself:

```
define( ['angular'], function (angular) {
'use strict';

/* Root herausfinden */
var root = window.location.pathname.split( "/" )[1];

var httpServices = angular.module( 'httpServices', [] );

httpServices.factory( 'sharedApplication', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    var sharedApp;
    sharedApp = {};
    sharedApp.currentView = "home-section";
    sharedApp.pastEvents = null;
    $http.get( "/" + root + "/api/search/md:ProductManager/" ).success( function (response) {
        return sharedApp.pastEvents = response.data;
    } );
    return sharedApp;
}] );

return httpServices;
} );
```

Our problem is, that we simply can not get/access the data of the $get-call. We always get an object, which looks like this:

```
Object {_invokeQueue: Array[1], _runBlocks: Array[0], requires: Array[0], name: "httpServices", provider: function…}
```

We guess that something is wrong with the timing of our ajax-call or the way we use the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally managed to solve the problem this morning. It was easier than expected.

The first thing that needs to be done is to change the line:

```
sharedApp.pastEvents = null;
```

To:

```
sharedApp.pastEvents = {};
```

So now "pastEvents" becomes a "pointer".

You also have to add the factory as a dependency in the angular module.
The line:

```
var app = angular.module( "clientapp", ['ngRoute'] );
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
var app = angular.module("clientapp", ['ngRoute', 'httpServices']);
```

With the corrected code you are able to use the factory in your controller like this:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function (sharedApplication)
{
    console.info(sharedApplication);
});
```

"sharedApplication" now holds your data retrieved by the ajax call in "sharedApplication.pastEvents".

EDIT:

If you don't want the http.get to execute immediately you can wrap it in a function like this:

```
sharedApp.testFunction = function ()
    {
        $http.get("/" + root + "/api/search/md:ProductManager/")
           .then(function (response){
             sharedApp.data = response.data;
           });
    };
```

Your pointer (sharedApplication.pastEvents) is now empty until you execute the function (sharedApplication.testFunction();).

Best regards

Timo

Comment: Isn't sharedApp already a pointer to an object? So changing  sharedApp.pastEvents = null; to sharedApp.pastEvents = {}; does nothing?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It didn't point to the response data until i changed the line. I'm not that familiar with pointers in Javascript. Maybe I'm wrong.

Btw. we now changed our code to return the "$http.get object" itself. It's now easier to react to the ajax call because we can access "then", "success", "error" etc.